# The concept of straight through estimator (STE)

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I have seen straight through estimator (STE) in many Neural Network related papers e.g. [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3432v1.pdf) and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06160.pdf). But I cannot understand the concept.  I wonder if anyone could explain STE or refer me to a simple resource?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A straight through estimator is a way of estimating gradients for a threshold operation in a neural network. The threshold could be as simple as the following function,

[image]

As we can see, the derivative of this threshold function will 0 and during back-propagation, the network will not learn anything since it gets 0 gradients and the weights won't get updated.

The concept of a straight through estimator is that you set the incoming gradients to a threshold function equal to it's outgoing gradients, disregarding the derivative of the threshold function itself. This has been shown to perform well in the results (Figure 2) in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3432.pdf) paper you have referenced.